# Upgrading from MySQL 5.5 to 5.6 and getting "SQLException: Connection is closed"

Tags: java, mysql, playframework-2.0, connection-pooling, bonecp

I am using the Play Framework with eBean. Upgrading to MySQL 5.6 has caused the following exception when running my database evolutions:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Connection is closed!
 com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.checkClosed(ConnectionHandle.java:459)
 com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle.prepareStatement(ConnectionHandle.java:1011)
 play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$.prepare(Evolutions.scala:128)
 play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$.updateLastProblem$1(Evolutions.scala:247)
 play.api.db.evolutions.Evolutions$.applyScript(Evolutions.scala:289)
 play.api.db.evolutions.EvolutionsPlugin.handleWebCommand(Evolutions.scala:584)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$handleWebCommand$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:193)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$handleWebCommand$1$$anonfun$apply$5$$anonfun$apply$6.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:192)
 scala.collection.LinearSeqOptimized$class.foldLeft(LinearSeqOptimized.scala:110)
 scala.collection.immutable.List.foldLeft(List.scala:83)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$handleWebCommand$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:192)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$handleWebCommand$1$$anonfun$apply$5.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:191)
 scala.Option.flatMap(Option.scala:170)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$handleWebCommand$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:191)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication$$anonfun$handleWebCommand$1.apply(ApplicationProvider.scala:191)
 scala.Option.orElse(Option.scala:266)
 play.core.ReloadableApplication.handleWebCommand(ApplicationProvider.scala:189)
 play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$1.apply(Server.scala:69)
 play.core.server.Server$$anonfun$getHandlerFor$1.apply(Server.scala:69)
 scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:125)
 scala.util.control.Exception$Catch$$anonfun$either$1.apply(Exception.scala:125)
 scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:103)
 scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.either(Exception.scala:125)
 play.core.server.Server$class.getHandlerFor(Server.scala:69)
 play.core.server.NettyServer.getHandlerFor(NettyServer.scala:37)
 play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$10.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:157)
 play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$10.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:157)
 scala.util.Either.fold(Either.scala:99)
 play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.messageReceived(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:142)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
 com.typesafe.netty.http.pipelining.HttpPipeliningHandler.messageReceived(HttpPipeliningHandler.java:62)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelHandler.java:88)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
 org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpContentDecoder.messageReceived(HttpContentDecoder.java:108)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
 org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:459)
 org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:536)
 org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
 org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
 org.jboss.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
 org.jboss.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
 java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
 java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I also found this in the application log:

```
    2015-01-29 09:13:03,742 - [ERROR] - from com.jolbox.bonecp.ConnectionHandle in New I/O worker #1 
Database access problem. Killing off this connection and all remaining connections in the connection pool. SQL State = HY000
```

I've tried with both mysql-connector-java 5.1.18 and 5.1.34 and I've tried with Play 2.3.6 and 2.3.4. Nothing seems to solve this issue except for using MySQL 5.5 instead of 5.6.

Comment: Step 1: rather than just trying stuff obtain actual information. Either find a way to make bonecp spit out more debug/trace logging or create some test code and manually try to create a connection (without a datasource in between) to your database to see what specific error that might produce. Right now you only have an "its not working". One thing to note is that 5.1.18 is definitely going to be too old so don't use that anymore.

Comment: Thanks Gimby, I was able to solve it after checking the bonecp logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After turning on logging from bonecp, I was able to identify which SQL statement was causing the connection to close. I was trying to change a foreign key column without dropping the foreign key. The reason MySQL 5.5 works and 5.6 doesn't is because of the following (from the release notes in 5.6):

> As of 5.6.7, the server prohibits changes to foreign key columns with the potential to cause loss of referential integrity. A workaround is to use ALTER TABLE ... DROP FOREIGN KEY before changing the column definition and ALTER TABLE ... ADD FOREIGN KEY afterward.